# python pandas - unable to resample timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas

I have timeseries data that looks like this:

```
                  ticker        close
created_at                                   
2020-06-10 18:30:00+00:00   TSLA  1017.419312
2020-06-10 17:02:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.354980
2020-06-10 17:03:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.922302
2020-06-10 17:04:00+00:00   TSLA  1015.626709
2020-06-10 17:05:00+00:00   TSLA  1016.400024
2020-06-10 17:06:00+00:00   TSLA  1017.223389
2020-06-10 17:07:00+00:00   TSLA  1016.110107
2020-06-10 17:08:00+00:00   TSLA  1016.109985
  ..........................................
```

I am trying to resample using 5 minute interval here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT created_at,ticker,close FROM market_data_history WHERE ticker='TSLA' and CREATED_AT > '2020-06-10 00:01:00+00' AND created_at < '2020-06-11 00:01:00+00'",index_col='created_at',con=engine)
# df = pd.read_csv("market_data_history.csv", usecols = ['created_at','ticker','close','volume'])
print(df)


d=df.resample('5T')
print(d)
```

However, the output is just showing

```
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<5 * Minutes>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]
```

Not sure why it isn't getting applied can someone please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resample` can be viewed as a kind of a group-by function. You need to specify how you'd like to aggregate resampled data.

For example:

```
df.resample("5T").max()
```

would produce:

```
                          ticker        close
created_at                                   
2020-06-10 17:00:00+00:00   TSLA  1015.626709
2020-06-10 17:05:00+00:00   TSLA  1017.223389
2020-06-10 17:10:00+00:00    NaN          NaN
2020-06-10 17:15:00+00:00    NaN          NaN
2020-06-10 17:20:00+00:00    NaN          NaN
2020-06-10 17:25:00+00:00    NaN          NaN
...
```

Comment: Thanks Roy! I thought the default aggregate method was mean hence initially i didn't apply... well something new learnt today! Thanks v much

Comment: If this answers your question, it would be great if you could accept it as an answer for future generations.

Comment: I will mark it as an answer I just need to wait for 15 minutes. Can you just confirm best practise for me. I have this time series data which is at minute interval and all I want to do is get the close price at every 5 minutes. I believe resample is the best way to do this, would you agree? Thanks again

Comment: I think resample is fine. There's a longer discussion about the different types of operations here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#window-and-resample-operations